# How to create a link that triggers printing of a file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, printing

I have some small images and each has a "print larger image" link.

For example:

```
<img src="thumb.jpg">
<a href="#">Print Larger Image</a>
```

When the user clicks the "print larger image" link, my goal is to trigger the printing of "big.jpg".

How can this be done?

**EDIT: ANTHONY HAD THE RIGHT SOLUTION FOR ME. I MODIFIED HIS CODE A BIT TO GET IT WORKING. HERE'S THE FULL, WORKING CODE**

```
<style>
@media screen {
.printimage {
     display: none;
}
}

@media print {
body * {
    display: none;
}
.printimage {
     display: block;
}
}

</style>

<a id="bigimage" href="#">Print Big Image</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#bigimage").click(function() {
          $("body").append("<img src='http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png' class='printimage' >");
          window.print();
     });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Printing means displaying, right?

Comment: If it did, this would be a duplicate of a question from a few minutes ago.

Comment: By printing, I don't mean displaying. Here's my goal: When a user clicks the "print" link, he stays on the same page and the browser's "print" dialog appears. Next, the user may click the "OK" button to begin printing the file "big.jpg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be really weird and awesome, but one thing you could do is:

Have the `print large image` link trigger a javascript function that inserts the larger image into the DOM with a class of "printable_image".

Then have your CSS rules set up with an `@screen` and `@print` rules that hide the image in the browser but hide everything but the image for the printout.

Then call the already mentioned `window.print()` function.
The only catch is that users wouldn't see anything if they just wanted to print the screen, so you'd have to add the @print rule with the js to avoid this.

The HTML:

```
<img src="thumb.jpg">
<a href="#" id="bigimage">Print Larger Image</a>
```

The JS (in jquery):

```
$function() {
     $("#bigimage").click(function() {
          $(body).amend("<img src='bigimage.png' class="printimage" />");
     });
});
```

The CSS:

```
@media screen {
.printimage {
     display: none;
}
}

@media print {
body * {
    display: none;
}
.printimage {
     display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: good solution, but that sounds to me like too much work ;) Very creative. Plus there is always the possiblity that a user has javascript turned off . . . .

Comment: If they have js turned off, then none of the given solutions will work, homie.

Comment: true.  you could just instruct the user to right click and open image :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="javascript:window.Print(); return false;">Print Larger Image</a>
```

This will print the current page, but to add to JoostK's answer, redirect to the image:

```
<a href="page.php?image=big.jpg">Print Larger Image</a>
```

Then in page.php, load your image, and then in body onload event, call window.print();

**EDIT:**

To allow the user to stay on the same page, I don't believe is possible, but what you could do is:

```
<a href="page.php?image=big.jpg" target="_blank">Print Larger Image</a>
```

Then after calling `window.print();` you can call `window.close();` (this might pop a dialog box stating that the browser wants to close the current window is that ok, or something along those lines)

Comment: I would like the user to stay on the same page after the "print" button is clicked. Is there a way to make that happen with AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

window.print() will do it in javascript, but that will only print the current page. If you're trying to launch the img into a new tab and run the print command, you'll have to combine a few commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="thumb.jpg" alt="Alternative text" />
<a href="big.jpg">Print Larger Image</a>
```

That's really basic HTML, no JS/PHP or whatsoever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link like this to print the current page...

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.print();">Print this page</a>
```

or to auto print a page as soon as it loads, you can do something like this...

```
<body onload="window.print();">
```